# Which type to use for Realm filter results

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am currently implementing a search with Realm's filter method. My filter-code looks like that:

```
filteredComm = realm.objects(Community.self).filter("name CONTAINS[c] '\(searchText)'")
```

As much as I know, I get a NSArray as an result. However, if I am trying to create an NSArray like that `var filteredComm: [NSArray] = []` i get the error:

```
Cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type NSPredicate
```

What is the best way to store the filtered Data in a variable, so I can use it in a different Method?

Answer (score 2):

The type of a realm filtering is `Results<T>`, where `T` is `Community` in this case.

You can convert it to a List like this:

```
var filteredComm = List(realm.objects(Community.self).filter("name CONTAINS[c] %@",searchText))
```

or to an array:

```
var filteredComm = Array(realm.objects(Community.self).filter("name CONTAINS[c] %@",searchText))
```

String interpolation is not encouraged when using NSPredicates, so you should use the variable value substitution method that I have used in the above code to generate the predicate.